# Rendering these Angular2 components with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, material-design

I need to achieve the following. Could you please give me some advice or recommendations to go in the right direction? Thanks.

**Goal to achieve:**

Complete the file: `index.html` (code below) by adding needed `CSS AND JAVASCRIPT` references so it can render the components: {`<mat-select />`, `<mat-slide-toggle />`, `<mat-datepicker />`} taken from here: https://material.angular.io/components.

Probably will be necessary to add some `JAVASCRIPT CONFIGURATION CODE` inside the `head / script` tag.

```
<!-- file: index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<!-- BEGIN OF CSS AND JAVASCRIPT -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
...
<!-- END OF CSS AND JAVASCRIPT -->

<script type="text/javascript">
// BEGIN OF JAVASCRIPT CONFIGURATION CODE
...
// END OF JAVASCRIPT CONFIGURATION CODE
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- ... -->

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="State">
            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <br />

    <!-- Please, alert its value every time it changes -->
    <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>

    <br />

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- ... -->

</body>

</html>
```

**Requirements:**

1. everything have to be inside: `index.html` (no sibling files).
2. reference every needed JavaScript file from some CDN server.
3. use the components / tags: { `<mat-select />` , `<mat-slide-toggle />` , `<mat-datepicker />` } directly in the `index.html`.
4. when you open `index.html` in the browser you get the same output as either:

- Pure `JavaScript` [live output](https://zeuscronos.github.io/angular-material-select/javascript/) and [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeuscronos/angular-material-select/master/datepicker.html).
- Pure `TypeScript` [live output and code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc?file=app/select-reset-example.html).

5. do not use replacing `jQuery UI` components.

The idea behind this is to get the same result as for the following `Angular1` (not `Angular2`) example. Where inside the `index.html` was used the `Angular1` component: `<sm-range-picker-input />`. Here are the [live output](https://zeuscronos.github.io/angular-material-select/datepicker.html) and the [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeuscronos/angular-material-select/master/datepicker.html) for this example which as you can see, it meets the 5 requirements pointed above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to work so hard to archive this. For example latest Angular release coming with Angular CLI component that will do all of this for you.

What is actually happening behind the scenes is that Angular CLI use [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) bundler to 1. Compile all TS files to JS files 2. Pack, compress, divide to chunks JS files, etc.. etc.. etc.. The output of all those processes is `bundle` file. Usually it named `main.js` or similar. This pure Javascript file contains **everything** you need to use (in you example) tags such as `mat-select`, `mat-slide`, etc.. The main point that it's already there - you don't need to bring Angular from CDN or anything else - it's already packed inside `main.js`.

General recommendation:

1. Read more on how Angular works with bundlers: [Angular Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)
2. Read more on how Webpack work: [Webpack concepts](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) and especially: [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)

Note: You could bring global CSS styles (for example) and put it into `<head>` section or even other JS packages. There's a way in Angular to use it inside application although they defined outside